# angle brackets notation statistics

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, average

I am working on a project that involves brownian motion. What does the notation  $<r_{ij}(0)r_{ij}(\tau)>$  mean if $r_{ij}(t)$ is the separation distance between particle $i$ and $j$ at time $t$?

Its some sort of average I'm guessing but of what and how do you calculate?

Thanks

Comment: In physics that is pretty standard notation for the expectation value.

Comment: that's what I thought, I'm mostly confused on what it's the expected value of? Is it the expectation of the product of the two?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Can you provide a link to the resource you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a bit more information? Is this a two-object Brownian motion?  I am trying to understand what it means and the context.

Offhand it looks like an inner product, of course. But that is just a guess based on the form.

Comment: There are two particles connected by a spring, and they are diffusing around in a viscous fluid. I am trying to construct an autocorrelation function of their bonds, this was part of the notation used describing the autocorrelation function. Thanks again

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.bimanbagchi.com/courses/ss207/notes/Lecture_note_6.pdf